# Mind your head or mind the table

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

He was bending himself under the table to look for something.

> "Mind your head."
>
> "Mind the table."

Do they sound natural in the context above?

Comment: I would say "Watch your head." in the sense of avoiding injury. And "Don't hit the table." if you are worried about the table or things on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either sounds natural, and it would depend on which item the speaker was worried about—the head or the table.

Comment: "Mind the table" can also mean you are worried about the head though.

Comment: @Stephen: True - but *Mind the **vase**,* for example, is much more likely to mean *Don't break my vase!* than *Be careful not to hurt yourself on my vase!*